# How to inject accessibility.properties file in running java application for screen recording?

Tags: java

For java screen recording need to enable from accessibility.properties file.

```
assistive_technologies=com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge
```

This setting is not enable while application start.So i wants enable this setting via **Java agent** injection in running java application.

As per as below link, This file load from **jaccess.jar** when application start.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/introduction.htm

How to inject this file via java agent/programmatically in running application?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)

Comment: Thanks, It is loading agent only.But i want to enable assistive_technologies via this agent.

Comment: Can you access JConsole and set it through JMX?

Comment: Can you please provide brief of JMX?